# having trouble with global variables in C

Tags: c

It seems that I can not save a global variable any help?  Here is the part of the code that seems to be the trouble: PS: the (`#include` are included)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void signup_user(char nameuser[10], char suruser[10],
                 char addressu[20], char usernameu[10],
                 char passuser[5]);
extern char nameuser[10] = "", suruser[10] = "",
            addressu[20] = "", usernameu[10] = "",
            passuser[5] = "";

int main {
    signup_user(nameuser, suruser, addressu, usernameu, passuser);
}

void signup_user(char nameuser[10], char suruser[10],
                 char addressu[20], char usernameu[10],
                 char passuser[5]) { //synarthsh signup
    printf("give name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &nameuser); //dinei onoma

    printf("give surname: ");
    scanf(" %s", &suruser); //dinei epitheto

    printf("give address: ");
    scanf(" %s", &addressu);

    printf("give username: ");
    scanf(" %s", &usernameu); //dinei username

    printf("give password: ");
    scanf(" %s", &passuser);
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including a complete program that demonstrates the problem, sample input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and the output desired instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not describe what you do (*p.s the (#include are included)*) but show it in the code. Please also show what errors you get. What problem do you have with your code? Do you know what `extern` keyword does?

Comment: Why do you think the code "can not save a global variable"?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but one problem I see is that, for example, `nameuser` is a string, which in C is a pointer, but then you pass `&nameuser` to `scanf`, which is a pointer-to-a-pointer. You should remove the `&` from all of your `scanf`s.

Comment: If you did not get a warning about a mismatch of types in `scanf` (expected `char*` vs provided `char(*)[]`) you might check your compiler manual how to turn up diagnostics level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @SGeorgiades: `nameuser` is not a pointer; it is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not compile. Do not use keywords you do not understand (`extern`).
Format your code properly. Learn about arrays and pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void signup_user(char *, char *,char *, char *, char *);
char nameuser[10]="", suruser[10]="", 
     addressu[20]="", usernameu[10]="", passuser[5]="";




int main(void )
{
    signup_user(nameuser, suruser, addressu, usernameu, passuser);
}


void signup_user(char nameuser[10], char suruser[10], char addressu[20], char usernameu[10], char passuser[5]) 
{
    printf("give name: ");
    scanf(" %9s", nameuser);//dinei onoma

    printf("give surname: ");
    scanf(" %9s", suruser);//dinei epitheto

    printf("give address: ");
    scanf(" %19s", addressu);

    printf("give username: ");
    scanf(" %9s", usernameu);//dinei username

    printf("give password: ");
    scanf(" %4s", passuser);
}
```

Also you should check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: Shadowing global variables with identical argument names is quite confusing too :)

Comment: @chqrlie main passes the correct references.

Comment: Yes, lucky OP :)

Comment: sorry for the previous comment